# Can I show independence of $2$ random variables with this?

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

Suppose I have $2$ random variables $X$ and $Y$. If I proved:

$$P(X = x, Y \leq y) = P(X = x)P(Y \leq y) = f_X(x)F_Y(y)$$

Would this show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: $P(X=x)$ is a probability while $f_X(x)$ is presumably a density so you need to decide which you are interested in.  If $P(X = x, Y \leq y) = P(X = x)P(Y \leq y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, and $X$ was a discrete random variable, i.e. $\sum_x P(X = x)=1$,  then you would have independence.

Comment: To add to Henry's comment, I observe that your equation $$P[X=x,Y\leq y]=P[X=x]P[Y\leq y] \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$ is true whenever $X$ has a continuous CDF (since it yields $0=0$ in that case). So, if that equality implied independence, it would mean all random variables with continuous CDFs are independent of all other random variables.